# syntaxerror in Thonny ide with nothing wrong why?

Tags: python, linux, syntax-error, raspberry-pi3

[image]

also this is on my Raspberry pi 3
Within Raspbian os

Update: after deleting all unnecessary script.. its working well also thanks so much for helping

This is all code in script  :

```
 Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

> > > print('hello world')

Comment: You are confident that there is nothing wrong with `f.py`, but the first two lines are clearly not valid Python code.

Comment: your screen capture starts from line 4. can we see the first 3 lines?

Comment: Please share your whole `f.py` file in the question, line 4 at the very least won't compile

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImkyS.jpg)Because of the additional information in the code which I thought did not affect the code ... but the solution is to scan everything in the code to verify its validity .. Anyway, I'm still a beginner and I have a lot to learn